# Probability Distributions for durations of sequential runs of sleep stages

Tags: probability, distributions

I am reading [this paper](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpregu.00925.2007) and trying to understand the math behind figure 5:

[image]

I am new to probability theory, but I believe that the y-axis represents the log of the pdf (probability density function) calculated for durations of each of the sleep stages. As sleep occurs in stages, awake stage can occur and last for, say, 10 mins, 30 mins, 40 mins and so on throughout the night (at least, this is what I gather by what "sequential run" means).

To quote from the paper:

> Distributions of durations of three sleep stages are shown in Fig. 5. To verify that the data from individual recordings for awake, REM, and non-REM sleep periods are respectively drawn from the same probability distribution, we applied the nonparametric Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and compared the probability densities pairwise between subjects for all individual sleep stages.

Does this imply that in figure 5, what is plotted is for 1 healthy subject and 1 CFS subject such that their data is drawn from the same probability distribution? I am sorry, I don't know if this makes sense, but can someone explain the theory/context behind the paragraph above and figure 5?